# Ajax request fail over https on iOS browser but not through http

Tags: ios, angularjs, iphone, angularjs-http

Hi thanks in advance for the help.

We're running a mobile web app that has been working fine on all browsers when it originally went live earlier this year.

About the app:

- Running on IIS 8.5.
- Certificate is from LetsEnctrypt.org
- REST web service is running on .NET Web API 2.
- Front end is AngularJS

Sample Ajax Call:

```
    $http.post('/api/User/Validate', loginData)
         .then(function (response) {
             alert("_login.Success: " + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
             if (response.data.StatusCode == 200) {

                 //console.log("Successfult Validate" + response);
                 var token = response.data.Data[0].Token;

                 var authData = {
                     token: token.TokenStr,
                     expiryDate: token.ExpiryDate,
                     companyId: response.data.Data[0].CompanyId,
                     userId: response.data.Data[0].UserId
                 };

                 _setAuthData(authData);                      

                 deferred.resolve(response.data);
             }
             else {
                 console.log("Error while validating ", response);
                 deferred.resolve(response.data);
             }


         }, function (err, status) {
             alert("_login.Error: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 4) + " " + status);
             _logOut();
             deferred.reject(err);
         });
```

I've added debug logging to troubleshoot this and i see the request hit that backend without any errors that i can see but when the browser gets the request the error callback function gets executed instead of the success one. If i try the same code through http it works perfectly.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear but when the app is through https i make the calls through https and vice versa; Http always works.

Comment: This only happens on iOS Safari browser.The error on the console says "An error has occurred" with the statusText of "internal server error" but i can see the request hitting the backend and returning successful results.